# Contar o número de ocorrências de um valor numa list

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma `list` com os seguintes valores:

```
numeros = [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Em Python teria alguma função para contar quantas vezes algum valor se repete?

Por exemplo: Quero saber quantas vezes o `5` repetiu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Usando Python 2 ou 3

Só usar o método [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
numeros = [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
numeros.count(5)
```

Comment: No Python 2.7 também funcionou :p

Comment: Sim. Acabei de ver que funciona pros dois

Comment: Eita, minimalista! Python ♥

Answer (score 17):

Pode usar o [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
numeros = [5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
repetidos = collections.Counter(numeros)
print(repetidos[5])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z9qwgg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/naiauvbl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/Counter.py).

Se preferir a forma curta:

```
print(collections.Counter([5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5])[5])
```

Comment: Bacana, o  `Counter` retorna uma estrutura semelhante a um `dict` com atribuição chave valor...

Comment: Acredito que essa deveria ser a resposta aceita, por ser bastante mais geral que a resposta do @LINQ

Comment: @LuizAngioletti "bastante mais geral" se refere a poder iterar e pegar a quantidade de repetições de cada um? (essa me parece a unica diferença de ambas)

Comment: @LuizAngioletti, talvez o caso do AP seja só de fazer a contagem de um único número el específico e depois ele vai esquecer a coleção. Nesse caso, a resposta do LINQ estará mais adequada do que essa. Caso seja necessário fazer múltiplas contagens aí sim está estratégia agrega muito mais do que a outra