# Como verificar e imprimir valores que se repetem em um vetor em Algoritmo

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Criar um algoritmo que dada uma sequência de n números reais, determinar os números que compõem a sequência e o número de vezes que cada um deles ocorre na mesma.

Exemplo: n = 8

Sequência:

```
-1.7,  
3.0,  
0.0,  
1.5,  
0.0,  
-1.7,  
2.3,  
-1,7
```

Saída:

```
-1.7 ocorre 3 vezes

 3.0 ocorre 1 vez

 0.0 ocorre 2 vezes

 1.5 ocorre 1 vez

 2.3 ocorre 1 vez
```

Fiz no VisualG
Código:

```
ALGORITMO "QUESTAO 9"
VAR
C,X,SEQ,I: INTEIRO
VSR: VETOR[1..100] DE REAL
SEQUENCIA: VETOR[1..100] de REAL

INICIO
ESCREVA("QUANTOS NÚMEROS REAIS COMPÕEM A SEQUÊNCIA? ")
LEIA(SEQ)
ESCREVAL("INFORME A SEQUÊNCIA: ")
PARA I DE 1 ATE SEQ FACA
LEIA(SEQUENCIA[I])
SE (SEQUENCIA[I])<>(VSR[I]) então
VSR[I]<-SEQUENCIA[I]
fimse
fimpara
para X de 1 ate SEQ faca
C <- 0
para I de 1 ate SEQ faca
se (VSR[X] = SEQUENCIA[I]) então
C <- C + 1
fimse
fimpara
escreval(VSR[X], " OCORRE ", C, " VEZES")
fimpara
escreval(" ")
escreval(VSR[X], " OCORRE ",SEQUENCIA[SEQ], " VEZES")


fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Parece que a sua pergunta contém alguns problemas. Nós não faremos o seu trabalho da faculdade ou lição de casa, mas se você estiver com dificuldade em alguma parte específica, compartilhe o seu código, diga o que já tentou fazer e qual está sendo a dificuldade, assim você aumenta as suas chances em conseguir uma boa resposta. Não deixe de ler o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/100416) para ter uma experiência melhor por aqui.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Obter quantas vezes cada elemento de uma lista se repete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414937/obter-quantas-vezes-cada-elemento-de-uma-lista-se-repete)

Comment: A menos que tenha ocorrido erro de digitação o valor -1.7 ocorre duas vezes, e não três, em sua lista de 9 elementos.

Comment: O método `Counter` da lib `collections` resolve isso. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176255/contar-o-n%c3%bamero-de-ocorr%c3%aancias-de-um-valor-numa-list)

Comment: @OverPeas, fica difícil de ver o código no `comments`. Atualiza seu post, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que é isso que vc busca.

**Update**

```
N = int(input("Quantos números? "))

lista = []
for i in range(1, N+1):
    lista.append(float(input(f"{i} - Entre com o número: ")))
```

**NOTA**: Não estão sendo tratados erros de digitação

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lista)
```

### Exemplo de Resultados

```
print(f"Lista de numeros: {list(c.keys())}")

Lista de numeros: [-1.7, 3.0, 0.0, 1.5, 2.3]
```

```
for numero, repeticoes in c.items():
    print(f" O numero {numero} repete {repeticoes} vezes")

 O numero -1.7 repete 3 vezes
 O numero 3.0 repete 1 vezes
 O numero 0.0 repete 2 vezes
 O numero 1.5 repete 1 vezes
 O numero 2.3 repete 1 vezes
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Isso mesmo @Paulo Marques, muito obrigado.